# How to solve this special Riccati equation? $\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} t}=ax^2+bt^n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} t}=ax^2+bt^n$$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$. Could you give a hint of how to solve this? I'd like to solve it as much as possible myself.

Comment: the solution containes the Bessel function

Comment: I found that out online, but I don't know how to use that hint :P. I have no experience with the Bessel function.

Comment: @Programmer2134: perform a change of variable, $t\to z^\alpha$, in order to turn such DE into a Bessel differential equation - http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html

Comment: Note that “ricatti” in Italian means “blackmail”. `;-)`